# Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I get the following error when I run my application:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> GuideMedApp.Models.NetworkPrescriber_Patients: : Multiplicity
>   conflicts with the referential constraint in Role
>   'NetworkPrescriber_Patients_Source' in relationship
>   'NetworkPrescriber_Patients'. Because all of the properties in the
>   Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role
>   must be '1'.

I'm trying to create a relationship between entities 'NetworkPrescriber' and 'Patient'. The Patient entity has 2 foreign keys pointing to the NetworkPrescriber table.

Here's how the Models are defined:

**Patient**

```
[Table("Patient")]
public partial class Patient
{
    public long PatientID { get; set; }

    public long? NetworkPrescriberID { get; set; }

    public long? SecondaryNetworkPrescriberID { get; set; }

    public virtual NetworkPrescriber NetworkPrescriber { get; set; }

    public virtual NetworkPrescriber NetworkPrescriber1 { get; set; }

}
```

**NetworkPrescriber**

```
[Table("NetworkPrescriber")]
public partial class NetworkPrescriber
{
    public NetworkPrescriber()
    {
        Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
        Patients1 = new HashSet<Patient>();

    }

    public long NetworkPrescriberID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients1 { get; set; }

}
```

The model configuration is as below:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkPrescriber>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Patients)
                .WithOptional(e => e.NetworkPrescriber)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.NetworkPrescriberID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkPrescriber>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Patients1)
                .WithOptional(e => e.NetworkPrescriber1)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.SecondaryNetworkPrescriberID);
```

The error is suggesting there's a mismatch between how the model are defined and how they're configured withfluent API but I don't see any.
How to I fix this error?

Comment: Could you please show all configurations?

Comment: @MegaTron This is the only configuration I have for these 2 entities

Comment: Try to add a full configuration for the model

Comment: I don't see any problem with what you have shown either. And cannot reproduce. There must be something else not shown here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
   .Property(p => p.NetworkPrescriberID).IsOptional();
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
  .Property(p => p.SecondaryNetworkPrescriberID).IsOptional();
```